# ant uppercase vs lowercase characters in path

Tags: java, linux, ant

I have an ant target that copies a file from one location to another, say it is defined in the `build.xml` as:

```
 ${project}/some-component-ABC/lib/whatever.jar
```

But on the file system the actual path is

```
 ${project}/some-component-abc/lib/whatever.jar
```

No uppercase ABC in some-component-abc on the fliesystem...

This path will resolve in Windows (7) but not in Linux?

Why?

I'll figure out what to do with it, just wanted some background why the functional difference.

Comment: because linux is case sensitive

Comment: Because Windows does not have case sensitive file paths and *unix has case sensitive file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the following article: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1227827
Linux is written in C, which is case sensitive. It makes for faster sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Ant doesn't do anything fancy with paths - it just delegates down to the underlying filesystem. Windows' filesystem is not case-sensitive, while any linux filesystem I can think of is. So, in windows, `some-component-abc` and `some-component-ABC` are the same directory, while in linux they would not be.

Comment: I can't believe it took me this long to recognize such a simple difference, never run into this issue before

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, for the most part Ant just stores strings for everything and relies on the OS's filesystem when it actually comes time to perform filesystem operations, so you will run into differences like this when running scripts in Linux vs Windows.

However, Ant does have tasks that manipulate path-like strings, and these can be used to groom references to files prior to using them. Here's an example:

```
~/test $ ls -1
build.xml
FILE
```

build.xml:

```
<project>
    <pathconvert property="file">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="file" casesensitive="false" />
    </pathconvert>

    <echo message="${file}" />
</project>
```

Output:

```
[echo] /home/me/test/FILE
```

Alternative approach (will return a path-like string relative to the fileset's `dir` attribute):

```
<project>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="file" casesensitive="false" id="filepath" />

    <property name="file" refid="filepath" />

    <echo message="${file}" />
</project>
```

Output:

```
 [echo] FILE
```

Comment: interesting, didn't notice casesensitive attribute in fileset tag